# filter the data from table using angular on the basis of checkbox clicked

Tags: angular

```
<div style="height:30px;width:60px;float:left"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="A" />&nbsp;&nbsp;A</div>
<div style="height:30px;width:60px;float: left"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="B" />&nbsp;&nbsp;B</div>
<div style="height:30px;width:60px;float:left"><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="C" />&nbsp;&nbsp;C</div>
```

I want that when checkbox A has clicked the data in column 1 with value A is only shown in the table and if checkbox B is also clicked then both  value  A and b are shown in table

```
<tr *ngFor="let sample of oilsamples">
    <td class="{{sample.evalcode | lowercase}}-bg eval">{{sample.evalcode | uppercase}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.sampledate  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.cust_name}}:{{sample.custid}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.site_name}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.serialno}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.unitno}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.modeldesc}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.compart}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.labno}}</td>
</tr>
```

How to use a filter for that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

```
<tr *ngFor="let sample of oilsamples| filterdPipe:a:b:c">
    <td class="{{sample.evalcode | lowercase}}-bg eval">{{sample.evalcode | uppercase}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.sampledate  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.cust_name}}:{{sample.custid}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.site_name}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.serialno}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.unitno}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.modeldesc}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.compart}}</td>
    <td>{{sample.labno}}</td>
</tr>
```

Pipe should be like

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterPipe' // name here
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: [], a: string, b: string, c: string): any {
        let result =[];
       // code here 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to angular can you plz provide me the whole solution thanks in advance

Comment: this is a solution. only you need to write code in pipe based on your requirement.

Comment: If performance or minification comes to an issue, maybe move filtering and sorting to a service: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe